# TradingView Pine Editor - How to not join changing values in one line?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api, mt4

Here is my current pine script plotting opens and closes:

```
plot(swt ? weekOpen : na, title="Weekly Open", style=line, linewidth=2, color=green,transp=0)
plot(swt ? weekClose  : na, title="Weekly Close", style=line, linewidth=2, color=red,transp=0)
plot(spw ? monthClose : na, title="Monthly Close", style=circles, linewidth=3, color=black, transp=0)
```

This is what it looks like:
[image]

I want the style to be a `line` and behave like the circles, except not being circles because they are not very accurate. I don't want the changing values to join up, how do I do this?

This is what my script looks like on MT4 (different code):
[image]

Comment: Have you tried `line_br` ?

Comment: Yeah, works the same as a normal line for me for some reason